# UITableView beginUpdate and endUpdate on last cell reloads tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview with expand-collapse cells. Whenever a cell is selected, I simply call :

```
tableView.beginUpdate()
tableView.endUpdate()
```

This in turns recalls the heightForRowAtIndex method, where I set the new height and this seems to show expand-collapse behavior.(without reloading the cell).

ISSUE: When I tap on last cell(or last 2-3 cells), after tableView.beginUpdate()
    tableView.endUpdate(), the table reloads itself. I have no clue why it is behaving like this.
It seams like since there is no space at the table's bottom to expand a cell, it's reloading itself.

Can someone throw light on this?

Comment: Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRowAt`?

Answer (score 0):

estimatedHeightForRowAt works always.